# no titlebar in fragment activity for android

Tags: android, fragment, android-theme

I want to hide title bar from swipe tab fragment activity , but when i write no title bar theme in manifest and run the app it have errors and don`t do anything , what should i do ? here is code:

```
public class Fragment1 extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {


ActionBar actionbar;
ViewPager viewpager;
@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
  super.onCreate(arg0);
  setContentView(R.layout.fragment);


  viewpager= (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
  viewpager.setAdapter(new Myadapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
  viewpager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        actionbar.setSelectedNavigationItem(arg0);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});;
  actionbar=getActionBar();
  actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

  ActionBar.Tab tab1=actionbar.newTab();
  tab1.setText("All Stuffs");
  tab1.setTabListener(this);

  ActionBar.Tab tab2=actionbar.newTab();
  tab2.setText("Top Stuffs");
  tab2.setTabListener(this);

  ActionBar.Tab tab3=actionbar.newTab();
  tab3.setText("New Stuffs");
  tab3.setTabListener(this);

  actionbar.addTab(tab1);
  actionbar.addTab(tab2);
  actionbar.addTab(tab3);

}
@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}
@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    viewpager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

}
@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

}


 }

 class Myadapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
 {

public Myadapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment=null;
    if(arg0==0)
    {
        fragment=new FragmentA();
    }
    if(arg0==1)
    {
        fragment=new FragmentB();
    }
    if(arg0==2)
    {
        fragment=new FragmentC();
    }
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 3;
}


 }
```

and it is my manifest code:

```
activity android:name=".FragmentA" 
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all please check your manifest:

```
activity android:name=".FragmentA" 
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

Your activity name is Fragment1. So this line is pointless. You cannot give theme to fragment is xml.

Before setcontentview method place this line:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

This will hide the title bar.

Answer (score 0):

In `onCreate` method try:

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

It will hide title bar